# Colouring and texturing 3d shapes with OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm trying to learn some OpenGL ES for Android, entirely for fun. Graphics programming is very new to me, so sorry if this is a stupid question.

I've read a few examples and tutorials, and can create shapes, move the camera with touch events etc. Following Google's tutorial, I modified it to make some 3d shapes. I'm happy with all of this so far.

Currently my shapes have the same colour on all sides, and it isn't clear to me how I colour/texture them separately with the code that I've got at the minute (I just built on the Google tutorials by experimenting basically).

All the other examples I look at use glDrawArrays rather than glDrawElements. Defining a shape this way seems a lot clumsier, but then you have a unique set of vertices which makes colouring (and normals) seem more obvious.

The draw method for my cube is below so you can see where I'm at. Do I have to do this differently to progress further? If so, doesn't that make glDrawElements a lot less useful?

```
public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) {
    // Add program to OpenGL environment
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

    // Enable a handle to the vertices
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    // Prepare the cube coordinate data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
            mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

    // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

    // Set color for drawing the Cube
    GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

    // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");

    // Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);

    // Draw the cube, tell it that vertices describe triangles
    GLES20.glDrawElements(
            GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length,
            GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To color a certain part of a shape you need to define the color per vertex. That in your case means you need another attribute next to `vPosition` which represents the color. In the shaders you will need add this new attribute and add a varying vector to pass the color to the fragment shader. No transformations are needed in vertex shader though. Also do not forget to enable the color attribute array and to set the pointer...

Try doing so to begin with and specify a different color for each vertex to see what happens.

If you will do this correctly you will see that each face of the cube now has a gradient color and only the corners of the cube have the exact color you specified. This is due to interpolation and there is not much you can do to fix this but create the vertex buffer differently:

So this is where the difference between drawing arrays or elements come in. By using elements you have an index buffer to lower the actual vertex buffer size by reusing the same vertices. But in the case of the cube with colored faces those vertices can not be shared anymore as they are not the same. If you want to have a cube with 6 different color each representing a single face you can see that each vertex (corner) actually contains 3 different colors, one for each face. So the vertex containing a position and a color must have the same both position and color to actually be the same...

So what must be done here is you need to create not 8 but 3*8 vertices and indices to draw such a cube. After you will do so you can see that number of indices and used vertices is the same so you gain nothing by using elements (but you still can if you wish) so it is easier to simply draw the arrays.

This same situation on a cube will happen for normals or texture coordinates, you simply need to make 8*3 vertices.

Note though that a cube is just one of those unfriendly shapes for which you need to do this. If you rather draw a sphere with some large amount of triangles you would not need to inflate the vertex count to do a nice texturing or lighting (using normals). In fact, tripling the sphere vertex count and doing the same procedure as on a cube would make the shape look worse.

I suggest you try playing around a bit with this kind of shapes, normals, colors, textures and you will learn most from own experience.